# jQuery .size() question

Tags: javascript, jquery

When you click the "Add Div" button, why doesn't the number increment?

http://jsfiddle.net/cN2zR/

Comment: jQuery recommends using .length instead of .size() http://api.jquery.com/size/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/cN2zR/3/ It does now :)

make d a function so it can be run each add.

```
var d = function(){
   return '<div class="historyItem">Test ' + ($("#history > div").size() + 1) + '</div>';
}
```

Also I noticed your problem with the scroll link. A quick trick to scroll to the bottom of a container is using the `.scrollTop([arbitrary high number])`

Answer (score 2):

`size()` is being evaluated once, when the value is assigned to `d`. You'll need to move the assignment inside the function to evaluate it each time.

Or, if you want it to keep it outside, you can make it into a function:

```
var d = function() { return '<div class="historyItem">Test ' + ($("#history > div").size() + 1) + '</div>'; }
```

then

```
$('#history').append(d());
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the size of the jquery result is calculated inline and ont everytime you use .
You can instead change d to a function that returns the HTML string and use it so that you get the size calculated every time you refer to it.

```
d = function(){
    return '<div class="historyItem">Test ' + ($("#history > div").size() + 1) + '</div>';
}

$('#b').click(function() {
    //console.time("timing Time");
    $('#history').append(d());
    //console.timeEnd("timing Time");
    $('#history').scrollTo('max');
});
```

Check this Post: http://jsfiddle.net/cN2zR/7/